# Scala - Handling transactions whilst not blocking

Tags: scala, rest, api, transactions

I'm building a Scala REST API to handle orders and I have been following https://github.com/alexandru/scala-best-practices to ensure I am following best practices as it's been a while since I wrote any Scala code.

So far, all of my code is thread safe and non blocking, using Futures where applicable and immutability throughout.  Now, i've integrated a data store that handles the creation of orders, my problem is that how do I deal with transactions (such as two orders exactly the same being created at the same time)?

Are there any patterns or examples that I can follow for handling transactions whilst preserving thread safety and avoiding non blocking code? I come from a Java background and typically would  use synchronised blocks but that would not respect:

**4.8.** https://github.com/alexandru/scala-best-practices/blob/master/sections/4-concurrency-parallelism.md

> Meet Amdahl's Law. Synchronizing with locks drastically limits the parallelization possible and thus vertical scalability. Reads are embarrassingly paralellizable, so avoid at all times doing this:

```
 def fetch = synchronized { someValue }
```

> Come up with better synchronization schemes that does not involve synchronizing reads, like atomic references or STM. If you aren't able to do that, then avoid this altogether by using proper abstractions.

I would appreciate guidance and/or examples of how this can be achieved.

Comment: When you say two orders that are exactly the same, do you mean they are duplicates? Because two orders can have the same make up but are generated separately, in which case they'll be two different but similar orders.

Comment: I guess that leads to the next question: How are these orders generated? Could it be the case that they are truly unique and it's okay to persist both?

Comment: These orders are duplicate and not unique @airudah

Comment: In that case, a common pattern is to attempt persist both. Since both will have the same unique identifier, the second write should fail and this could then be handled gracefully using the your existing Futures pattern.